# Ignore fsck / zero-padded file mode errors in "git clone"

Tags: git, git-fsck

I have the following settings in my global Git configuration:

```
[transfer]
    fsckobjects = true

[fetch]
    fsckobjects = true

[receive]
    fsckobjects = true
```

These verify that all objects in the cloned database are valid and reachable.

However, some repos I want to check out have errors, like `oh-my-zsh`:

```
git clone https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git .oh-my-zsh 
Cloning into '.oh-my-zsh'...
remote: Counting objects: 15624, done.
error: object 2b7227859263b6aabcc28355b0b994995b7148b6: zeroPaddedFilemode: contains zero-padded file modes
fatal: Error in object
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Is there a way I can override my global fsckobjects settings for a single "git clone" operation?

Comment: With Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), you will be able to ignore that error, with `git -c fetch.fsckobjects=true -c fetch.fsck.unterminatedheader=warn clone https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git .oh-my-zsh`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51918148/6309).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `git clone --config key=value` and pass all of the arguments you want to skip there. For `oh-my-zsh`, that looks like this:

```
git clone --config transfer.fsckobjects=false \
    --config receive.fsckobjects=false \
    --config fetch.fsckobjects=false \
    git://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git
```

Answer (score 3):

Git 2.19 (Q3 2018) will now allow to get past that error (transformed as a warning).

The test performed at the receiving end of "`git push`" to prevent bad objects from entering repository can be customized via `receive.fsck.*` configuration variables.
We now have gained a counterpart to do the same on the "git fetch" side, with
`fetch.fsck.*` configuration variables.

See [commit 8a6d052](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a6d0525b74fe07bde0436e4cbf87b23adf7df0a), [commit 65a836f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65a836fa6bf9e9cf604e22855e744af61e708664), [commit d786da1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d786da1cd9c43b6747c78811a4b6ab2028dfaf50), [commit 1362df0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1362df0d41311beac8c778030ad0e8dcc2ef9af2), [commit 8b55b9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b55b9db23962c5623f724d9ec857226dab9631a), [commit 720dae5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/720dae5a19074e404224c9051152d7c64ba2acf0), [commit 456bab8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/456bab87b2e5e698f1024df7a79a76627b4bdb32), [commit b2558ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2558abdc471758ae8b30c1198e833a7a1c6616c), [commit 5180dd2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5180dd2e9ffb46eb02ee24439f2cd24a534d2954), [commit 95d9d4b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95d9d4b30cd5a7eece51a3d6b26023bb5da3378e) (27 Jul 2018) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f8ca718](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f8ca71870a4265320fbbecb4f676d0ad1d4bf176), 17 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `fetch`: implement `fetch.fsck.*`
>
> Implement support for `fetch.fsck.*` corresponding with the existing
>   `receive.fsck.*`. This allows for pedantically cloning repositories with
>   specific issues without turning off `fetch.fsckObjects`.
>
> One such repository is https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git
>   which before this change will emit this error when cloned with
>   `fetch.fsckObjects`:
>
> ```
> error: object 2b7227859263b6aabcc28355b0b994995b7148b6: zeroPaddedFilemode: contains zero-padded file modes
> fatal: Error in object
> fatal: index-pack failed
> ```
>
> Now with **`fetch.fsck.zeroPaddedFilemode=warn`** we'll warn about that
>   issue, but the clone will succeed:
>
> ```
> warning: object 2b7227859263b6aabcc28355b0b994995b7148b6: zeroPaddedFilemode: contains zero-padded file modes
> warning: object a18c4d13c2a5fa2d4ecd5346c50e119b999b807d: zeroPaddedFilemode: contains zero-padded file modes
> warning: object 84df066176c8da3fd59b13731a86d90f4f1e5c9d: zeroPaddedFilemode: contains zero-padded file modes
> ```
>
> The motivation for this is to be able to turn on `fetch.fsckObjects` globally across a fleet of computers but still be able to manually clone various legacy repositories by either white-listing specific issues, or better yet whitelist specific objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the latest version – such as for automated installs – I have been using this in my scripts ([for example](https://github.com/CristianCantoro/cms_deploy/blob/master/provision/zsh/install_ohmyzsh.sh#L70)):

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh
```

It does not clone the whole repo history, just the latest version, which should be ok anyway for automated installs.

(I am quite sure I did not come up with this myself, but I am unable to retrace it to the original source).